# Oracle SQL correlated subquery to fetch exactly one row

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics, correlated-subquery

In an Oracle SQL correlated subquery,

I require to have a condition on the subquery to fetch exactly one row(if there are more rows, it shouldn't fetch any rows).

And the below query works just fine. But it involves querying the same table twice.

```
SELECT m.pk_1
      ,m.pk_2
      ,m.fld_3
      ,(SELECT c.pk_1
        FROM   child_tab c
        WHERE  (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM   child_tab c2
                WHERE  c2.pk_1 = m.pk_1
                AND    rownum <= 2) = 1
        AND    c.pk_1 = m.pk_1) c_pk_1
FROM   master_tab m
WHERE  m.pk_1 = '018'
AND    m.pk_2 = 'value'
```

By redesigning the sub-query using analytic function,the below query gives error

```
SELECT m.pk_1
      ,m.pk_2
      ,m.fld_3
      ,(SELECT ch.pk_1
        FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) over() cnt
                      ,c.pk_1
                FROM   child_tab c
                WHERE  c.pk_1 = m.pk_1
                AND    rownum <= 2) ch
        WHERE  cnt = 1
        AND    c.pk_1 = m.pk_1) c_pk_1
FROM   master_tab m
WHERE  m.pk_1 = '018'
AND    m.pk_2 = 'value'
```

`ORA-00904 m.pk_1 is an invalid identifier`

Is there any better way to do this using Oracle SQL?

**UPDATE**

My real requirement is that I generate this SQL as a recursion process which leads many level like this. And the data I select will not be limited to the key. And I need only SQL solution, so PLSQL is not a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this. I do not have any way to execute and check this one. So, please let me know for any issues

```
   SELECT m.pk_1, m.pk_2, m.fld_3, C.PK1
   FROM MASTER_TAB M, CHILD_TAB C
   WHERE c.pk_1 = m.pk_1 AND m.pk_1 = '018'
   AND    m.pk_2 = 'value'
   AND EXISTS
   (
   SELECT *
   FROM CHILD_TAB C2
   c2.pk_1 = m.pk_1
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   )
```

**Edited:**

```
   SELECT m.pk_1, m.pk_2, m.fld_3, C.PK1
   FROM MASTER_TAB M, (
   SELECT c2.pk_1
   FROM CHILD_TAB C2
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
   ) C
   WHERE c.pk_1 = m.pk_1 AND m.pk_1 = '018'
   AND    m.pk_2 = 'value'
```

Comment: This query again do two selects on the child table and it will not work as you are doing `SELECT *` while `HAVING count(*)` which restricts the select to `GROUP BY` columns. Not using 'group by' will make you select none.

Comment: This also won't work. `SELECT c2.pk_1 FROM CHILD_TAB C2 HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` c2.pk_1 cannot be selected. Kindly read on "group by having"

Answer (score 1):

Oracle isn't able to push the value of `m.pk_1` into a subquery two levels down. However, given that you're supplying the value for `m.pk_1` in your top-level where clause, you could just put this directly into your scalar sub-query like so:

```
SELECT m.pk_1
      ,m.pk_2
      ,m.fld_3
      ,(SELECT ch.pk_1
        FROM   (SELECT COUNT(*) over() cnt
                      ,c.pk_1
                FROM   child_tab c
                WHERE  c.pk_1 = '018'
                AND    rownum <= 2) ch
        WHERE  cnt = 1
        AND    c.pk_1 = m.pk_1) c_pk_1
FROM   master_tab m
WHERE  m.pk_1 = '018'
AND    m.pk_2 = 'value';
```

Alternatively, given that `m.pk_1 = c.pk_1`, you don't need to select `c.pk_1` and can just check whether the rows exist using a case statement, returning `m.pk_1` if there's only one row:

```
SELECT m.pk_1
      ,m.pk_2
      ,m.fld_3
      ,CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM   child_tab c
                  WHERE  c.pk_1 = m.pk_1
                  AND    rownum <= 2) = 1 THEN
          m.pk_1
       END c_pk_1
FROM   master_tab m
WHERE  m.pk_1 = '018'
AND    m.pk_2 = 'value';
```

Finally, you could always create a PL/SQL function to do the lookup for you, returning null when there's `too_many_rows`. If you have a small number of different values for `m.pk_1` and you're using 11g, this could be a [result cache function](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=504), which should perform well:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_id(m_pk master_tab.pk_1%TYPE) RETURN child_tab.pk_1%TYPE AS
  retval child_tab.pk_1%TYPE;
BEGIN

  SELECT t.pk_1
  INTO   retval
  FROM   child_tab t
  WHERE  t.pk_1 = m_pk
  AND    ROWNUM <= 2;

  RETURN retval;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;

SELECT m.pk_1
      ,m.pk_2
      ,m.fld_3
      ,get_id(m.pk_1) c_pk_1
FROM   master_tab m
WHERE  m.pk_1 = '018'
AND    m.pk_2 = 'value';
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

My real requirement is that I generate this SQL as a recursion process which leads many level like this. So using your first approach of "hard-coded where clause" won't work.

And the data I select will not be limited to the key, so the 2nd approach won't also work for me.

And I need only SQL solution, so PLSQL is not a choice.

Comment: But these solutions fit well for the question I asked. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. I think you need to create a new question describing what you need explaining the business requirements.